# Non-failable initializer requirement cannot be satisfied by failable initializer

Tags: swift, struct, failable

I have this struct and I want its `init` to be `failable` because something could go wrong with the JSON dictionary I pass:

```
struct AdminModel:Interface{

var status:Any = ""
var l:String = ""
var p:String = ""
var url:String = ""

init?(json:NSDictionary){

    if let status = json["status"] as? Any,
       let l = json["l"] as? String,
       let p = json["p"] as? String,
       let url = json["url"] as? String
    {
        self.status = status
        self.l = l
        self.p = p
        self.url = url
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

There's no issue until I add `?` after init to make init `failable`: at that point XCode complains:

> Non-failable initializer requirement 'init(json:)' cannot be satisfied by failable initializer ('init?')

Why my struct can't be failable? Should I declare failable even the protocol init?

Comment: What is `Interface` ? Perhaps it requires a non-failable init?– Without that, your code compiles.

Comment: Interface is a protocol with a non-failable init, I suppose the error lies there, even if I read it elsewhere   :-)

Comment: That is the problem. The error message is quite clear, and your last sentence is the solution. – I am not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: I could delete the question but someone as silly/tired as me could benefit from your comment

Comment: @user1094081 But I still don't understand what is the solution! lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Interface` is like:

```
protocol Interface {
   init(json: JSON)
}
```

but your AdminModel's init is `init?(json: JSON)`, so you should keep consistent:

```
protocol Interface {
   init?(json: JSON)
}
```